# About CPU architecture terminology

Tags: cpu

is Core 2 Duo 2.4G  i686 or x86-64?

In my macbook pro 2010, it has core2 duo cpu
is this i686 or x86-64?

i am not sure~~~so i came here and ask.
and also, I also see some term says  amd64? what are differences among these?

thank you.

Comment: check the manufacturer's website and try googling

Answer (score 1):

It is Intel 64 (previously known as EM64T and IA32e). This instruction set is mostly compatible with AMD64 (previously known as X86-64). x86-64 is used as a vendor-neutral name for the common instructions.